# Django - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' only on SOME users, post migration?

Tags: django, migration, django-south

Recently I've been working on a system where we updated an application from a older Django version (which used South for migrations) to an up to date version (with integrated migration).

This morning the other person working on the server said there was an issue with the migrations, as something in the South migration was not correctly taken in to consideration, so he had to do a few extra steps to get the database to migrate correctly.

So I checked the application this morning, and things are working fine for me. But the site owner reported issues from her user account. She tried logging in another user account she had, and it worked fine. But her main account is getting the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

in the line...

```
<label>Age: <span class="uneditable-input input-mini form-control"> {{ visit.patient_age_at_time_of_visit }}
```

Here is the portion of the model related to that:

```
@property
def patient_age_at_time_of_visit(self):
    today = self.visit_date
    born = self.patient.dob
    try: 
        birthday = born.replace(year=today.year)
    except ValueError: # raised when birth date is February 29 and the current year is not a leap year
        birthday = born.replace(year=today.year, day=born.day-1)
    return today.year - born.year - (birthday > today)
```

Any idea how I could repair this issue, and/or why it would only be affecting certian user accounts? The latter issue worries me more...

Answer (score 0):

Some Patient accounts clearly have an empty field for `dob`.

Comment: Problem is, if she makes a new patient and adds a DoB on the new patient, this error still happens. Yet on my account, if I do the same steps, it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, you clearly have empty dob fields, but if you want to "fix" this exact issue, you will need to check for None and do something:

```
@property
def patient_age_at_time_of_visit(self):
    today = self.visit_date
    born = self.patient.dob

    if born is None:
        return None

    try: 
        birthday = born.replace(year=today.year)
    except ValueError: # raised when birth date is February 29 and the current year is not a leap year
        birthday = born.replace(year=today.year, day=born.day-1)
    return today.year - born.year - (birthday > today)
```

.

### Update:

I am guessing you are doing the following:

The property you have shown is part of some model probably called Visit.
Patient is also a model.
dob is a field on the Patient model.

You are most likely assigning dob like this:

```
visit = Visit.objects.get(id=some_id)
visit.patient.dob = some_dob
visit.save()
```

This in fact does not work. You have to save the patient, not visit. So it should be:

```
visit = Visit.objects.get(id=some_id)
visit.patient.dob = some_dob
visit.patient.save()
```

And you don't even have to save visit because technically nothing changed on it.

### Update:

Edited the update above from "A" to Visit after noticing that it must be called that.

Comment: Problem is, if she makes a new patient and adds a DoB on the new patient, this error still happens. Yet on my account, if I do the same steps, it works fine? It seems the information does not correlate from account to account?

Comment: I put the comment into the answer since the formatting was too hard to read.